# Restoring Time Machine backup do a different user folder location

Tags: time-machine

I have a 27" iMac. Its original 1Tb drive failed a few days ago. I decided to replace it with a 2Tb drive and replace my CD/DVD drive with an SSD drive. The SSD drive is small - 128Gb. I intend to only have the OS and install apps there. All user data will be on 2Tb drive. Restoring all data on OS drive and moving it over is not an option - complete backup is 465Gb. Is there a way to force TM to restore my files where I want them?

Comment: I thought mapping /Users folder to my 2Tb volume would solve the problem. Unfortunately, TM seems to concentrate on the boot SSD drive as its prime restore target.

Answer (score 2):

Simply mount your time machine backups volume then navigate to /Backups.backupdb//Latest.  Under there is your latest backup.  You can then copy and paste the files manually wherever you want them.